# htaccess 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm a htaccess noob and atm I'm trying to sort out a mess left by the previous webmaster of a website.

I have instances such as the following

```
http://www.domain.com/Home
http://www.domain.com/Home/
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home/
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home/Home
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home/Home/
```

which all need to 301 redirect to `http://www.domain.com/`

The following works

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule ^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{4,15}|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{3,15}\/)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I then also have instances such as the following:

```
http://www.domain.com/calendar.asp
http://www.domain.com/Calendar.asp
http://www.domain.com/calendar.asp?foo=123&bar=456&foobar=123456
http://www.domain.com/Home/calendar.asp?foo=123&bar=456&foobar=123456
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home/Home/Calendar.asp
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home/calendar.asp
http://www.domain.com/Home/Home/Home/calendar.asp?foo=123&bar=456&foobar=123456
```

etc etc

which all need to 301 redirect to `http://www.domain.com/events/`

The following two work for dealing with the calendar page issues in their multiple variations...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule ^calendar\.asp$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/events\/?" [R=301,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule ^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{4,50})\/[cC]alendar\.asp$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/events\/?" [R=301,L]
```

but... I doubt my attempt at this would be considered optimal and wondering how it should be done as opposed to me and my limited knowledge hacking something together.

Any help appreciated

Thanks
Whims

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `RedirectMatch` for both:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(Home/?)+$ http://www.domain.com/
RedirectMatch 301 /[Cc]alendar\.asp$ http://www.domain.com/events/
```

In the instance of the "Home", the regular expression matches any number of /Home/'s and in the instance of calendar, you're only checking if it ends with Calendar.asp or calendar.asp.

Comment: try again.. sorry

Hi Jon Lin

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(Home/?)+$ http://www.domain.com/

Works a treat

However

RedirectMatch 301 /[Cc]alendar\.asp$ http://www.domain.com/events/

is giving mixed results.. 

eg calendar.asp?event_id=87 redirects to the correct directory however it now retains the query params eg /events/?event_id=87

calendar.asp?month=1&day=17&year=2020&submit=Show+on+the+Calendar
ends up with a 404

Thanks
Whims

Sory if this post looks a mess.. not sure how to edit it so that it looks correct.. apologies

Comment: just to clarify too.. my "try again" is directed at myself,.. not you.. my first attemps to reply to you went pearshaped when I accidently hit enter and I had to delete it..

Comment: Ahh, I see, you can add a **?** at the end of the redirected URL so the query string won't get appended, so thaat it looks like this: `http://www.domain.com/events/?`

Comment: Yes, if I add ? at end of the redirected URL it removes the query string however I am then left with something like /events/? which is not what I am wanting to be left with. Nor do I want to remove all query strings, only those from the incorrect urls.

Quick q.. what is the advantage of
`RedirectMatch 301 /[Cc]alendar\.asp$ http://www.domain.com/events/` over
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule ^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{4,50})\/[cC]alendar\.asp$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/events\/?" [R=301,L]`